# Component space trace is not working while Splitting serilog file in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, saml, serilog, component-space, serilog-filter

Due to some technical reasons we have separated logs and errors files into two individual files using serilog . In this case , logs and errors from component space  trace alone is not getting  logged

```
"Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "Override": {
                "Default": "Debug",
                "Microsoft": "Information",
                "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
                "ComponentSpace": "Debug"
            }
        },
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "Logger",
                "Args": {
                    "configureLogger": {
                        "Filter": [
                            {
                                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                                "Args": {
                                    "expression": "(@l in ['Error', 'Fatal', 'Warning'])"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "WriteTo": [
                            {
                                "Name": "File",
                                "Args": {
                                    "path": "Logs/WebApp/Errors/error_.log",
                                    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                                    "rollingInterval": "Day"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "Logger",
                "Args": {
                    "configureLogger": {
                        "Filter": [
                            {
                                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                                "Args": {
                                    "expression": "(@l in ['Information', 'Debug'])"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "WriteTo": [
                            {
                                "Name": "File",
                                "Args": {
                                    "path": "Logs/WebApp/Informations/log_.log",
                                    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                                    "rollingInterval": "Day"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "Enrich": [
            "FromLogContext",
            "WithMachineName"
        ],
        "Properties": {
            "Application": "MultipleLogFilesSample"
        }
    },
```

Please refer the below serilog configuration which am using

I have also followed the below link to enable trace ,
https://www.componentspace.com/Forums/7936/Enabling-SAML-Trace?Keywords=serilog
which works good when i had the same configuration with name as "**Serilog:Async**" , but my problem is i have split the individual logger for log and error using the name "Logger", so in this case component space trace is not working .

Note: Hi thanks for replying , am not having these configurations on appsettings.json file instead am having these in a custom json file and the path of that custom json file is added in the appsettings.json file

Below code snippet is used for loading the log configuration from custon file

```
 var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(KestrelServerOptionsExtensions.GetBasePath()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
        string ConfigPath = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:ProlaborateConfigPath").Value;//ConfigPath
        var Logconfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(ConfigPath).Build();
        var functionDependencyContext = DependencyContext.Load(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(Logconfiguration, "WebApp:Logger", dependencyContext: functionDependencyContext).CreateLogger();
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's not working? I used the exact same Serilog configuration and ComponentSpace Debug entries were written to the log file in the logs\WebApp\Informations folder.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying , am not having these configurations on appsettings.json file instead am having these in a custom json file and th path o that custom json file is added in the appsettings.json file